# rails 3 habtm filtering with multiple entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

i have a **product** model and a **product category** model. and theres a **habtm** between those.

i have categories like 'men' and 'jeans' and i would like to filter these. to do a filter on men is no problem but i need to filter multiple parameters (men and jeans). i tried some variations but i'm stuck on this.

this is what i have so far..

```
Product.joins(:product_categories).where(['product_categories.id = 5 and product_categories.id = 6'])
```

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the solution which selects men AND jeans and not men OR jeans:

```
@products = Product.scoped

@product_category_ids.each.with_index do |product_category_id, index|
  @products = @products.joins("INNER JOIN product_categories_products pcp#{index} ON pcp#{index}.product_id = products.id AND pcp#{index}.product_category_id = #{product_category_id}")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

How about writting it like this and passing array of ids you're looking to filter by?

```
Product.joins(:product_categories).where(['product_categories.id in (?)', _product_categories_ids ])
```

Comment: hm i figured out that this doesnt solve my problem..

if i select men and jeans.. i dont want women jeans.. this is what happens with the code above.. IN is like OR.. right? i need AND.. how i can achive this?

thanks